# Conflict with Group By and sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Tags: mysql

Here is the query:

```
SELECT c.*, f.file
FROM `category` c
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT `file`, catId
    FROM `file`
    ORDER BY sortId
) f
    ON f.catId = c.catId
GROUP BY c.catId
ORDER BY c.sortId
```

This used to work fine until a mysql update. I have been circling on this for a while now and I can't seem to find a solution.

Here is the last option I tried:

```
SELECT *
FROM `file`
LEFT JOIN `category`
    ON `file`.catId = `category`.catId
GROUP BY `file`.catId
ORDER BY `category`.sortId
```

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't even understand why you are using `GROUP BY`.  Please add sample input and output data to your question.

Comment: @Barmar, I'm not convinces any answer on the duplicate page sufficiently attempts to resolve assumed/implicit ordering of sub-queries to gain a specific result in the top query.

Comment: @danblack What implicit ordering? Even before the `only_full_group_by` change, it wouldn't return any specific row in the group. But I've added another dupe for finding the maximum row in each group in case that's what he thought it was doing.

Answer (score 0):

Using windowing you can get the highest rank. (based off [this](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=104))

```
SELECT r.*
FROM (
    SELECT c.*, f.file, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY catId ORDER BY sortId) AS rank
    FROM `file` f
    LEFT JOIN category c
        ON c.catId = c.catId
    ORDER BY f.catId
) AS r
WHERE r.rank = 1 
ORDER BY catId
```

Comment: This requires MySQL 8.0.